# AWS Codepipeline limitations on a single account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

We are planning to leverage AWS codepipeline by hosting it on a single AWS account, moving forward pipeline count will get around ~500, Is there any limitation by AWS that only certain number of pipelines needs to be hosted on a single account.
Do we need to have a separate account for hosting all these pipelines or just host these on the AWS account in which the application is running? what are the best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the limits pertaining to `CodePipeline` at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/limits.html.

It looks like as of now there is a soft limit is 300 pipelines per region per account. If you hit that number, you should be able to request an increase by following the link in that document.

Comment: What are the best practices in terms of hosting codepipelines, any Idea?

Comment: not sure I understand the question. You don't really host `CodePipeline` but you create CI/CD pipelines using `CodePipeline`. Use `AWS CloudFormation` or `AWS Cloud Development Kit (CKD)`  to create code pipelines.

Comment: I meant to say create

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, the default limit for pipelines per account per region is 300. This limit can be raised on request.

While you can run more than 300 pipelines per account, you may also start running into related limits like IAM roles per account, CloudWatch Event rules per account, etc. You can get these limits raised too, but the complexity of dealing with all this can start to add up.

My personal recommendation would be to split things across multiple accounts so that there are about 300 pipelines per account at most. If you have multiple teams or multiple departments, splitting accounts by team/department can be a good idea anyway.